# Getting error B0237W The Sample JSP client does not support arrays: {0}file Content web service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I am calling a [webservice](https://mr.eclaimlink.ae/MemberRegistration.svc?wsdl) using a wsdl: .

While creating a webservice client, it's giving me this error:

```
IWAB0237W The Sample JSP client does not support arrays: {0}fileContent
```

There is a method which is not supported. Does anyone have a solution to clear this error?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Eclipse/Java?  I was able to download the wsdl and generate a Webservice Client using the WSDL with Eclipse Mars 4.5.2.  I was also able to bring up the Webservices Explorer in Eclipse using the WSDL.  I don't have a valid login to the webservice so I couldn't test it.

Platform Stack I used :

- Mac OSX
- Eclipse Mars 4.5.2
- Java 1.7.0-79

I might download the latest Eclipse and try again.

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: i used eclipse mars 4.5.2 in windows java 1.7 but while loading this wsdlhttps://mr.eclaimlink.ae/MemberRegistration.svc?wsdl.I am getting the same error.should i need to use any other setting

Comment: Are you able to get UploadMemberRegistration method in that particular login??

Comment: No.  But I do see it in the WSDL.  I also see uploadMemberRegistration() methods in multiple Interfaces and classes.  Any chance or way you can validate the WSDL?  Its not clear what your looking for.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the generated code...hth, adym